# In the new version of Quake on Steam, how do I change my player name?

Tags: steam, quake

[image]

My player name is the annoyingly generic "steamuser" and I can't find any setting to change it.  In the non-Steam-ified version this was done in the Multiplayer menu under setup but that menu option does not exist here.

This is running on Linux and I get an error connecting to Bethesda.net every time I start the game, but it works fine in singleplayer at least (haven't tried multi).  A guess might be that this Bethesda.net error is why I can't find the setting, but that is just a guess. So...

How do I change my player name?

Comment: When I disable my internet and start the game, it still picks up my Steam name there, even with it failing to connect to bethesda.net.  But I am wondering if that is because I previously have played the game _with_ internet connection and successful connection to bethesda.net

Comment: @TimmyJim Maybe I should be working on trying to figure out why it won't connect to bethesda.net  I see that I already have an account there, and it's linked to steam, so the connection must have worked for some other game.

Comment: Perhaps relink your Steam account to bethesda.net if possible.  Maybe a previous password change or something invalidated your credentials.

Comment: @TimmyJim good suggestion - but it looks like the other bethesda.net game is Doom 2016 which works fine, and I don't want to mess that up in favor of Quake! Steam community forums show lots of problems with Quake/bethesda.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all came about because of not being able to connect to bethesda.net

I changed the proton version to specify 6.3.8, That allowed me to connect and then everything worked.

(Previously I was using proton-experimental)

Answer (score 1):

In Quake, the normal way would be to use the console (defaults to tilde) and type:

`name NameyMcNameyface`

This can also be added to your `autoexec.cfg`

https://www.quakewiki.net/console/console-commands/quake-console-commands

Comment: Thanks. I tried it in the Steam version. It accepted the console command without any error, but the name displayed on the menu screen as seen in the question did not change.